# Insertion using triggers by passing values

Tags: plsql, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

Lets say I have a table as follows--

```
create table employees 
(
 eno      number(4) not null primary key, 
 ename    varchar2(30),
 zip      number(5) references zipcodes,
 hdate    date
);
```

And I'm trying to create a trigger with--

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TWELVE_ONE
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE
ON EMPLOYEES
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
  V_DATE   VARCHAR2 (10);
BEGIN
      SELECT TO_CHAR (SYSDATE, 'hh24:mi:ss') INTO V_DATE FROM DUAL;
      IF (V_DATE >= '12:00:01' AND V_DATE < '13:00:00')
      THEN
          INSERT INTO TABLE ?????
      ELSE
          ROLLBACK? TERMINATE TRANSACTION?
      END IF;
END;
```

Purpose of the trigger is to allow an insertion/update during 12:00-13:00 and prevent the insertion at any other time. The trigger construction (thanks to @Melkikun) is seems ok. However now I'm facing the following issues--

How is it possible to pass the values here? I mean lets say my create statement is:

`Insert into employees Values (1, 'someone', 11111, '17-12-2015')`

And lets say the time is 12:30:01 now. How would the trigger perform the insertion without knowing the values?

And lets say the time is now 13:00:1 now. How would the trigger stop/prevent the insertion?

I'm using Oracle SQL Developer 4.02.15 
Many Thanks

Comment: Is use of trigger to impose the time rule seems ok? or should I start thinking about `function` or `stored procedures`?

Comment: Why 12:00:00 is not valid time?

Comment: Yes the use of a trigger is appropriated for your specific case.No need of a function or stored procedures ... even if you could do it this way.

Comment: @hinotf let's say its a business rule. More appropriately, office hours is between 9:00-6:00, and no alteration should occur before or after that hour

Comment: @envyM6 I see, just wonder why exactly 12:00:00 is not valid, but 12:00:01 is valid time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to do it the other way.

If the time is not correct,then you raise an **exception**, so the insert won't be done.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TWELVE_ONE
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE
ON EMPLOYEES
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
V_DATE   VARCHAR2 (10);
MyException exception;
BEGIN
  SELECT TO_CHAR (SYSDATE, 'hh24:mi:ss') INTO V_DATE FROM DUAL;
  IF (V_DATE < '12:00:01' OR V_DATE > '13:00:00')
  THEN
      raise MyException;
  END IF;
EXCEPTION
When MyException then
ROLLBACK;    
//output message ...
END;
```

> How would the trigger perform the insertion without knowing the values?

The trigger knows the value thanks to :NEW and :OLD.

You normally use the terms in a trigger using **:old** to reference the old value and **:new** to reference the new value.So you will have :NEW.eno ,:NEW.ename ...

Here is an example *from the Oracle documentation :*

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER Print_salary_changes
BEFORE DELETE OR INSERT OR UPDATE ON Emp_tab
FOR EACH ROW
WHEN (new.Empno > 0)
DECLARE
sal_diff number;
BEGIN
sal_diff  := :new.sal  - :old.sal;
dbms_output.put('Old salary: ' || :old.sal);
dbms_output.put('  New salary: ' || :new.sal);
dbms_output.put_line('  Difference ' || sal_diff);
END;
```

Comment: Thanks! But I still don't get it.. 

`BEGIN
  SELECT TO_CHAR (SYSDATE, 'hh24:mi:ss') INTO V_DATE FROM    DUAL;
  IF (V_DATE < '12:00:01' AND V_DATE > '13:00:00')
  THEN
      raise MyException;
  END IF;
EXCEPTION
When MyException then
//output message ...
END;`

What would be the complete `begin end` block in whole?

Comment: Instead of `//output message` in the exception block, you just have if you want to display a message, for example : `dbms_output.put('Hour is not correct,you can't insert now  : ' || V_DATE);`

Comment: I get that part. But when the time is lets say 12:30. the trigger should perform the insertion right? But how?

Comment: @envyM6 at 12:30 trigger just don't doing something special then INSERT complete as usual

Comment: You have moreover to write `ROLLBACK TRANSACTION`

Comment: SO Just to make sure.. here's the trigger--

`CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TWELVE_ONE
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE
ON EMPLOYEES
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
V_DATE   VARCHAR2 (10);
MyException exception;
BEGIN
  SELECT TO_CHAR (SYSDATE, 'hh24:mi:ss') INTO V_DATE FROM DUAL;
  IF (V_DATE < '12:00:01' AND V_DATE > '13:00:00')
  THEN
      raise MyException;
  END IF;
EXCEPTION
When MyException then
ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;   
dbms_output.put('Not Allowed at this time');
END;`

Comment: @Mxsky I have a compilation error on that, check the the scrrenshots

Comment: error message :

`Error at Command Line : 1 Column : 13
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-04098: trigger 'S12003330.TWELVE_ONE' is invalid and failed re-validation
04098. 00000 -  "trigger '%s.%s' is invalid and failed re-validation"
*Cause:    A trigger was attempted to be retrieved for execution and was
           found to be invalid.  This also means that compilation/authorization
           failed for the trigger.
*Action:   Options are to resolve the compilation/authorization errors,
           disable the trigger, or drop the trigger.
`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98240/discussion-between-mxsky-and-envym6).